# Grunt Spawn task and get result

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to create a grunt task which spawns a command window and get the results from the command.  As a Test I'm just running cd to get the current directory, (I've also tried cwd)

```
grunt.registerTask('random', function(){
    var done = this.async();

    grunt.util.spawn({
        cmd: 'cd'
    }, function(error, result, exitCode){
        console.log("callback hit");
        console.log(result);
        done();
    });
```

I'm getting an error that cd wasn't found

> callback hit
>   { stdout: '',
>     stderr: 'Error: not found: cd',
>     code: 127,
>     toString: [Function: toString] }

How can I execute a shell window in grunt and get the result back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grunt.registerTask('random', function(){

    var exec = require('child_process').execSync;

    var result = exec('cd', { encoding: 'utf8' });
    meta.version = result;
    grunt.log.writeln('version: ' + result);
});
```